# Как исправить java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, junit

Когда запускаю тест выдает ошибку `java.lang.NullPointerException` в `s1.setId(1)`. Как это исправить?

Весь код:

```
public class UserTest extends TestCase{
    private User user;
    private Series s1;

    public void setUp(){
        user = new User(1, "Dan", 4, 300);

        s1.setId(1);
        s1.setTitle("Mr. Robot");
        s1.setStatus(1);
        s1.setActors("Rami Malek, Christian Slater, Portia Doubleday");
        s1.setEpisodesCounts(10);
        s1.setRating(9.1);
    }

    public void test1(){
        User.getUserId(user);
    }

    public void test2(){
        user.loadUserSeriesLib();
    }

    public void test4(){
        user.addNewSeriesToLib(s1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Series s1;
```

в данной строке проведедено лишь объявление ссылки. но никакой инициализации объекта нет, т.е. s1 не знает куда ссылаться.

чтобы это исправить нужно проинициализировать поле s1:

```
s1 = new Series();
```

Answer (score 3):

Создать объект типа `Series` и присвоить ссылку на него полю класса `s1`:

```
public void setUp(){
    user = new User(1, "Dan", 4, 300);

    s1 = new Series();
    s1.setId(1);
    ...
}
```